# Change default value on a combo box

Tags: php, combobox

I am using osTicket and we'd like to change the default value on a combobox.

This is the code where the combobox is at:

```
    <tr>
        <td width="160">
            <?php echo __('Department'); ?>:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="deptId">
                <option value="" selected >&mdash; <?php echo __('Select Department'); ?>&mdash;</option>
                <?php
                if($depts=Dept::getDepartments()) {
                    foreach($depts as $id =>$name) {
                        echo sprintf('<option value="%d" %s>%s</option>',
                                $id, ($info['deptId']==$id)?'selected="selected"':'',$name);
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            &nbsp;<font class="error"><?php echo $errors['deptId']; ?></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I'd like for the default to be 'Unassigned', which is one of the options in the combobox:

[image]

When I made the change, I ended up adding the value again and then it does not save it.

This is my change, which did not work right:

```
<option value="" selected >Unassigned</option>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The selected value is whatever `$info['deptId']` is. I would try to set the value of `$info['deptId']` instead of modifying the posted code. It seems to be the case that you changed only the text of the empty option to "Uassigned" that is not a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another UNASSIGNED option coming from the database? Can we see the method getDepartments? The problem might be there. Take a look and tell me what you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could check within the foreach loop for the correct value then assign that value with the selected attribute.

```html
 <?php
                if($depts=Dept::getDepartments()) {
                    foreach($depts as $id =>$name) {
                    if($id === $info["deptId"]) {
                        echo '<option value="$id" selected="selected">$name</option>';
                     } else 
                            {
                       echo '<option value="$id">$name</option>';
                      }
                                
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: I'm not great with php and I tried this code and nothing changed. Am I supposed to change anything for it to select UNASSIGNED in the given code?  Right now, with your code, it is showing $name 6 times in the drop down list.

Comment: My question would be, are you trying to match the data from a dynamic data store or would it be ok just to hard code the selected value in? what I mean is, just stick the selected option before the foreach loop and delete the other "unselected" choice from wherever that list is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out what the correct value for the "Unassigned" option is.
You can do that by viewing the original HTML-Code. I suspect it is an integer like this:

```
<option value="7">Unassigned</option>
```

if the correct value for "Unassigned" is for expamle "7" you should try to find out what the default value for `$info['deptId']` is. You can do it by inserting a `var_dump($info['deptId'])` somewhere in your php-code next to the posted code. I suspect it is an empty string or NULL. Assuming it is an empty string you should insert the following code before your select is printed:

```
if($info['deptId'] == "") {
    $info['deptId'] = 7;
}
```

Because of the original logic the "Unsassigned" option should be selected if the value of `$info['deptId']` has the correct value for "Unassigned". The important code which is responsible for that behavior is this:

```
($info['deptId']==$id)?'selected="selected"':''
```